# Evaluate $\int_\frac{\pi}{4}^\frac{\pi}{2}e^x(\log\sin x+\cos x)\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Please help  me evaluate this integral:

$$\int_\frac{\pi}{4}^\frac{\pi}{2}e^x(\log\sin x+\cos x)\mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: Do you mean $\log(\sin x + \cos x)$?

Comment: Do you mean log or ln ?

Comment: @Fabien Is there a difference?

Comment: I hate when people exchange the two of them :)

Comment: @Fabien Also when people is lazy to use $\large\left(\phantom{AAAAA}\right)$'s.

Comment: @FelixMarin It's not lazyness. It reduces clutter.

Answer (score 3):

For reference. Mathematica has said:
$$\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2} e^x (\log \sin x + \cos x)\ \mathrm{d}x=\left(-\frac{1}{10}+\frac{i}{5}\right)e^{\pi/4}\left(-2\ {}_2F_1\left(1,1-\frac i2;2-\frac i2;i\right)-(4-2i)\ {}_2F_1\left(-\frac i2, 1; 1-\frac i2; i\right)+\sqrt{2}(1+2i)+(1+2i)(-\log 2) + e^{\pi/4}(1+2i)\left(((-1+2i)+\psi^{(0)}\left(-\frac i4\right)-\psi^{(0)}\left(\frac 12 - \frac i4\right) \right)\right)\approx  0.622023 $$
Which is a good indicator that that integral is not very solvable by hand.